# Validity of formulas

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

So i know that if  $(∃x ϕ)$ is valid that doesnt implie that doesnt implie that $ (∀x ϕ) $ is also valid, my question is if it is sufficient for me to get an interpretation stucture that satisfies the first and doesnt satisfy the second or i actually need to find a formula that works for every interpretation stucture and then show it doesnt satisfy the second, because it doesnt seem so easy to get that formula.

Comment: You need to show that an interpretation that satisfies the first formula does not necessarily satisfy the second. In other words, you need to find an interpretation where the first formula holds but the second doesn't.

Comment: Alright cool , thats what i did i just wasnt sure if that was enough , because every interpretation stucture has to satisfy the first one.